# Mishloach Manos from quarantine

Tags: purim, mishloach-manot, choleh-sick

[The Jerusalem Post quotes Rabbi Eliahu Birnbaum, director of the Straus-Amiel Institute of Ohr Torah Stone, as saying that if someone is quarantined due to the coronavirus they should send someone a nice note or call someone](https://www.jpost.com/HEALTH-SCIENCE/Can-a-person-in-home-quarantine-read-the-megillah-via-Skype-619923).

> “The gist of mishloah manot is to think about someone,” he told The Jerusalem Post. “By sending a nice note or calling one another to say happy holiday it sends a good feeling, and that way you preserve the mitzvah’s value.”

While this does preserve the value of the Mitzva, its really hard to say that too many opinions would feel this would fulfill the obligation of Mishloach Manos. It seems to me that there must be a better way for someone who is contagious on Purim to fulfill the Mitzva of Mishloach Manos according to more opinions.

The most obvious way would be to have a friend give someone two food items on your behalf which should work according to everybody. But even if that wasn't an option, there must be other ways that one can fulfill the obligation according to some opinions. Are there any other options?

Comment: I recommend you ask if you can send MM to family members and via amazon as two separate questions. VTC as too broad for now.

Comment: Isolation isn't really the point and doesn't fit with the first possibility I had mentioned.

Comment: Physical isolation is exactly the point of the question and fits with everything.

Comment: If you're quarantined in a hospital you could give to someone in the hospital, perhaps another quarantined person.

Comment: The Rav Low wrote recomendations

Comment: @Harel13 If two quarantined people who each *might* be infected have contact with each other, there is a chance one will infect the other.